# how to remove remove element from system.webServer/modules programmatically

Tags: c#, web-config

I'm trying to remove "remove" tag from system.webServer/modules section programmatically in c#

the web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="XXX" />
            <add name="XXX" type="XXX, XXXX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5dff614f906107a2" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>    

</configuration>
```